# How do I install Quantum ESPRESSO on Windows 10?

Tags: quantum-espresso, software, software-assistance, windows-operating-system

[Cross posted on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/kamran-elyas-916109142_struggling-to-install-quantum-espresso-on-activity-7127327350236585984-e6YP?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop)

Struggling to install Quantum Espresso on Windows 10 for vital DFT calculations due to missing GitHub libraries. Seeking assistance from the LinkedIn community. If you have expertise or resources to help, please reach out. Your support is greatly appreciated in advancing our research.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our community! Can you please provide a link to the LinkedIn post as well? That is basically our policy on cross-posting: you need to provide a link to all other places where you asked the question, so that if one place gets an answer, our community doesn't have to spend too much time answering it again unnecessarily. Also, if you're able to use Linux on your Windows 10 machine, then this is your answer: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10654/5, and if you do get it running on Windows 10, this might of interest: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6126/5